# REGEX: Match filename at beginning of string and parameter at end

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that matches the **thank-you.aspx** at the beginning of the string below and the **ty=1** at the end.  Those two components will always be the same, but all of the other information in the  middle will be different. I am using the regex to look for these particular thank-you.aspx URLs in a database.

**thank-you.aspx**?source=302454&ve=60493&fn=TestName%20&ln=TestName&leadimportid=0&**ty=1**

Comment: You ask for a regex, and then mention looking in a database. Which is it? If it's a regex, what flavor (Perl, MySQL, JavaScript, etc.) regex are you using? If it's a database, what database? What have you tried so far that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```
^thank-you\.aspx.*ty=1$
```

Answer (score 1):

`^thank-you.aspx\?.*?&ty=1$`

The `?` in `.*?` is to have a non-greedy repeat.

Comment: non-greedy is not necessary since you have the hard stop at "1$"

Comment: @SteveH. The necessity of it very much depends on the regex engine used, on which we don't have any info so far, so non-greedy is the safer bet.

Answer (score 1):

For a MySQL selection

```
SELECT db.table.url WHERE db.table.url REGEXP '^thank-you.aspx.*\&ty=1$'
```